# Spring Data JPA @Table annotation working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

`@Table` annotation does not seem to work. I have table `PERSON_INFO` in my MySQL database. And I have an entity class as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_INFO")
public class PersonInfo {

}
```

But it is getting error as:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'my_db.person_info' doesn't exist
```

Why does table name become lowercase even if it is explicitly defined in uppercase?

Comment: In which schema does that `PERSON_INFO` exists ?

Comment: @Deadpool The DBMS is `MySQL`. Aren't `schema` and `database` one in MySQL? A database has only one schema. My database is `my_db` so its schema is also `my_db`. I could be wrong though.

Comment: `schema` and `database` are different, so you need find the appropriate schema

Comment: In MySQL, it could be `case sensitive`, check if the table name is uppercase in the database. change it to lower case and try.

Comment: @Deadpool that is not true to MySQL `In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database. You can substitute the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax, for example using CREATE SCHEMA instead of CREATE DATABASE.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema

Comment: I only have one database.

Comment: @SunilDabburi like I said my table is `PERSON_INFO`. I can't change it. That is the reason I used `@Table(name = "PERSON_INFO")`.

Comment: check this @Julez https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-schema-and-database-in-mysql I might be wrong but i'm not sure about mysql

Comment: @Deadpool I have no problem with my database. It's been created. It was allowed by MySQL to be created, in the first place. By default Spring Data JPA uses lowercase for table so using `@Table` should allow to define table name if it is different.

Comment: I don't understand why in spite of using `@Table(name = "PERSON_INFO")` the table becomes lowercase, `person_info`.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities

Comment: Have you tried specifying schema="my_db"? What is your jdbc connection string? It may also be related to Hibernate physical naming strategy or Mysql case sensitiveness which works different between Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ` to force case sensitivity.
@Table(name = "`PERSON_INFO`")